# How to visualize the geocode of an adress ? and in ideal situation knowing if this is inside my polygon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mapbox, geocoding

I am doing a script for test if an adress is in an area, for exemple around a point. I use node.js for the server and then JavaScript with the API mapbox. I display the map with the polygon (the area), the central point and the search with autocomplete for adress.
But now I am wondering, how to have the geocode (lattitude and longitude) from the adress ?
I would like to take this coordinate for calculate if those coordinate are inside my polygon for example with one of those methods :
 http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html#wn_PinPolygon()

here my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Adress in/out area</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.3.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.3.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.4.1/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js'></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.4.1/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css' type='text/css' />
  <div id='map'>  </div>
  <script>
  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'mytoken';
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [-73.943851,40.720021],
      zoom: 13
  });
   var geocoder =new MapboxGeocoder({
  accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
  mapboxgl: mapboxgl
  });
  map.addControl(geocoder);
  geocoder.on('result', function(result) {
  console.log(result);
  });
  map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource("checked-area", {
      "type": "geojson",
      "data": {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
            [
            [-73.9346845,40.7284786],
            [-73.9382465,40.7281208 ],
            [-73.9457138,40.7274053],
            [-73.9517648,40.725454],
            [-73.9560993,40.721486],
            [-73.9564855,40.710394],
            [-73.9406068,40.7118904],
            [-73.9330966,40.713582],
            [-73.9347274,40.7172251],
            [-73.933955,40.7202501],
            [-73.9351995,40.722722],
            [-73.9282472,40.7243482],
            [-73.9298351,40.727633],
            [-73.9346845,40.7284786]
            ]
            ]
          }
        }, {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-73.943851,40.720021]
          }
        }]
      }
      });
      map.addLayer({
      "id": "area-boundary",
      "type": "fill",
      "source": "checked-area",
      "paint": {
      "fill-color": "#088",
      "fill-opacity": 0.5
      },
      "filter": ["==", "$type", "Polygon"]
      });
      map.addLayer({
        "id": "area-store",
        "type": "circle",
        "source": "checked-area",
        "paint": {
        "circle-radius": 6,
        "circle-color": "#B42222"
        },
        "filter": ["==", "$type", "Point"],
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is more specially this part of code which deals with the search part for adress :

```
  var geocoder =new MapboxGeocoder({
  accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
  mapboxgl: mapboxgl
  });
  map.addControl(geocoder);
  geocoder.on('result', function(result) {
  console.log(result);
  });
```

I would like from this code to take the coordinate to be able to calculate if they are inside the defined area (and in the future even without showing the map only with a message).
I tried with JSON.parse(result) and I have :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON

I also tried with result.geometry.coordinates and result['geometry']['coordinates']
If you have an idea you will help me a lot :)
PS: in case of minus please let me know why so that I could improve my post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON

This is mostly because you're trying to parse an object instead of JSON string. Have you tried accessing `result.result.geometry` instead. That gives the geometry.

```js
    geocoder.on("result", result => {
      console.log(result.result.geometry);
    });
```

You can also check if a point geometry lies within a polygon using turf.inside [1]

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/manishraj/full/bGbxOVG. Try searching for `Pune, India` and `Delhi, India`.

[1] https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-inside